# Отношение не существует Postgres. Запись подзапроса SELECT через AS

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, select

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос и мне подзапрос `select * from taxi_order` нужно через `AS` сделать отношение чтобы обратиться к нему в `where`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select * 
  from taxi_order 
  where driver_id = ANY (select id from driver where car_id = 4) 
) AS foo
where distance_km = (select max(distance_km) FROM foo);
```

Но мне выдает ошибку, что : ***ОТНОШЕНИЕ `foo` не существует!***

Comment: в СТЕ пихниве ваш запрос, а потом уже к нему пишите и селект и подзапрос на максимум.

Comment: @teran  что такое СТЕ?

Comment: общее табличное выражение

Comment: @ИванПавлов CTE - https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/queries-with  Но на самом деле он тут не нужен. Вы можете получить max() оконной функцией, прямо во внутреннем запросе https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/tutorial-window и во внешнем по ней отфильтровать `select * from (select *, max(distance_km) over() max_dist ...) foo where distance_km=max_dist`

Comment: `order by distance_km desc limit 1` же вообще без лишних подзапросов

Comment: @Мелкий Не согласен, что если таких записей больше 1